# Parsing deeply nested GraphQL Responses

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql

I have a GraphQL schema which I've created mutations & queries from for my Flutter App :

```
type Mutation {
  accounts: AccountsMutation!
}

type Query {
  accounts: AccountsQuery!
}

type AccountsMutation {
  auth: AuthenticationController!
}

type AccountsQuery {
  auth: AuthenticationQueryController!
}

type AuthenticationController {
  forgotPassword(email: Email!): Boolean!
  resetPassword(
    email: Email!
    password: Password!
    confirmPassword: Password!
    code: String!
  ): IdentityResult!
  login(email: Email!, password: Password!, rememberMe: Boolean! = false): User
  tokenLogin(
    email: Email!
    password: Password!
    rememberMe: Boolean! = false
  ): TokenLogin
  refreshAccessToken(refreshToken: RefreshToken!): RefreshedAccessToken!
  logOut: Boolean!
  register(
    email: Email!
    password: Password!
    confirmPassword: Password!
    locale: Locale
    timeZone: UserTimeZone
  ): User
}

type AuthenticationQueryController {
  currentUser: User!
  frontServiceToken: String!
}

scalar BOAccessToken

scalar BORefreshToken

scalar AccessToken

scalar Email

scalar ExternalId

type IdentityError {
  code: String
  description: String
}

type IdentityResult {
  succeeded: Boolean!
  errors: [IdentityError]
}

scalar Locale

scalar Password

type RefreshedAccessToken {
  isValid: Boolean!
  accessToken: AccessToken
  expiresIn: Int!
}

scalar RefreshToken

scalar RoleId

scalar RoleName

scalar SecurityStamp

type TokenLogin {
  user: User!
  accessToken: AccessToken!
  refreshToken: RefreshToken!
  expiresIn: Int!
}

type User {
  id: UserId!
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
  locale: Locale!
  timeZone: UserTimeZone!
  email: Email!
  firebaseToken: String
}

scalar UserId

scalar UserTimeZone

scalar UserTokenId
```

As you can see, my queries & mutations are **deeply nested**, how would you recommend **parsing my responses** ?

Currently I've created an `Accounts()` class that than parses an `Auth()` than than parses...

But I feel I'm creating unnecessary intermediary classes with this approach, are there better approaches more suited to GraphQL ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to this Link:

https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter

Use this :

```
graphql_flutter: ^5.1.0
```

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:trash_themes/themes.dart';
import './graphql_bloc/main.dart' show GraphQLBlocPatternScreen;
import './graphql_widget/main.dart' show GraphQLWidgetScreen;
import 'fetchmore/main.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'GraphQL Flutter Demo',
      theme: DraculaTheme().makeDarkTheme(context: context),
      home: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('GraphQL Demo App'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Spacer(),
                Flexible(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute<GraphQLWidgetScreen>(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                            GraphQLBlocPatternScreen(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('GraphQL BloC pattern'),
                )),
                Spacer(),
                Flexible(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute<GraphQLWidgetScreen>(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                            const GraphQLWidgetScreen(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('GraphQL Widget'),
                )),
                Spacer(),
                Flexible(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute<FetchMoreWidgetScreen>(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                            const FetchMoreWidgetScreen(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('Fetchmore (Pagination) Example'),
                )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```